# How to set equal space between CardViews in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have some **CardViews** in my **RecyclerView,** and when I want to set space between them by adding margin, I get this:

[image]

As you can see, distance between cards is double. If I for example set margin just for top, left, and right, problem is solved but last card will touch the bottom of screen, and I don't want it. Like this:

[image]

As you can see, all spaces are equal and good, but there is no space in the bottom.
I have a MainActivity.java, activity_main.xml, recyclerview_row.xml, and MyAdapter.java in my project.

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#dddddd">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my recyclerview_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My question is how can I set equal distance between these Cards. Thank you.

Comment: In your activity_main.xml's parent layout set padding bottom

Comment: I've try this before, but it makes an empty space at the bottom, and not good when scrolling.

Comment: @Arantik u needed a space at the bottom right or needed some space at the last item like the other items in list

Comment: one solution is in your getview  in adapter for the last item add a padding to the lastview by code . I think there is no direct solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `activity_main.xml` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#dddddd">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

The magic is done by this line: `android:clipToPadding="false"`

Comment: By setting margins Left, Right, and Top for CardView, and then this solution, My problem solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Arantik You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This in Main Activity,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#dddddd">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#dddddd">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dim_10"
        android:background="#dddddd">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```